# Can I buy a 24v transformer with a dedicated common c-wire feed?

Tags: thermostat, thermostat-c-wire, transformer, wifi

I have an oil furnace that feeds hot water to baseboard in four zones in my house and also to a hot water tank for tap water. 
There is a 24vac transformer with two output wires that feed power to the electric zone valves.
I want to change one thermostat in a bedroom to a Wifi unit that needs a c-wire.  I have read that I can connect the c-wire to the transformer (power stealing), but that is not recommended. I have 5 wires running to the old thermostat, but only Rh and W are connected.
I think a good option would be to just replace the old transformer with a modern one. Why is it that I cannot find an HVAC transformer that has a dedicated common terminal? To me this makes more sense then adding a second transformer.
Any recommendations?

Comment: Every HVAC transformer has a 'common' terminal. The 'common' terminal is whichever of the 2 terminals is *not* connected to the R terminal on your thermostat.

Comment: Are you referring to some sort of transformer/relay combination device when you say "transformer?"

Comment: No weird situation. The answer below looks correct to me. I have R and W, so I should connect my C from the thermostat to the transformer at the same terminal as W.

Answer (score 4):

Um, I don't know where you got the term "power stealing".  What you describe as that, is *exactly the normal way to do that thing*, and the right way... unless you are aware of some capacity issue on the transformer (as is sometimes seen in transformer-relay combos).

As far as the R and C terminals, any HVAC transformer has two pins on the 24V side... They are R and C.  The one that is not R is C.

Comment: I realize my error now. Power stealing is when a thermostat taps a small amount of power from the R and W lines to charge its internal battery.  I'm amazed with all the write-ups about adding a c-wire, nowhere have I seen someone explain so simply how to wire my situation. Thanks!